# Issues with MAUI deployment

Tags: maui, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-mac

I have developed a MAUI application using Mac VS 17.6.4 with the latest workloads installed for Xcode 15. I have tested the mobile app on my iPhone 12 after compiling the app in both debug and release modes and the app works as expected. However, when I build the .ipa for deployment to the Apple store the version that gets generated there crashes before it even shows the splash screen. I've tried setting different link options but that hasn't made a difference in the crash scenario.

I am creating the .ipa using the dotnet publish command (dotnet publish -f net7.0-ios -c Release -p:ArchiveOnBuild=true -p:RuntimeIdentifier=ios-arm64) which seems to generate things just fine. I am looking for suggestions on what to do to resolve this. Also, if there is a way to identify what is causing the crash I would appreciate some direction on that as well.

Comment: The issue is either with your certificates or with your build pipeline, the ipa is not being signed properly

Comment: If it was not signed properly it wouldn't be accepted by Apple into TestFlight. I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: Apple approved a crashing app?

Comment: It was accepted for TestFlight. The distribution certificate was appropriate for the app and it passed for submission.

Comment: Is there any error log trace for the crash? You need to locate on what causes the issue first.

Comment: There is no error log that I can find.

Comment: Instead of using command line, have you tried to manually publish, see [Publish an iOS app for App Store distribution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/publish-app-store?tabs=vs#publish-the-app)?